# Background worker stealing main thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker

So I can't say for sure this is the issue but I'm just about positive it is. I have a recordset of IVR calls to make. I put the data for each one in a concurrent queue and start 5 background workers to start working from the queue. However, after making 2 calls, the calls stop coming until one person hangs up, then it moves on to call number 3,4,5 etc. Are the any issues with this code?

It seems like the background workers are blocking eachother from calling the same method...? Is that possible?

```
private ConcurrentQueue<DataTable> _ivrCallsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DataTable>();

private List<BackgroundWorker> _ivrCallers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();

public overrid void Process()
{
 foreach(DataRow row in _tblRecordsToProcess.Rows)
    {
       _workingActionItem = actionItemDAL.GetActionItemFromId(Convert.ToInt32(row["FNActionItemId"].ToString()));

        var workingActionItemsTable = actionItemDAL.GetActionItemParamValues(Convert.ToInt32(row["FNActionItemId"].ToString()));

       ivrCallsQueue.Enqueue(workingActionItemsTable);
    }

    StartCalls();

  while (_ivrCallers.Count != 0)
  {
      testurls = testurls;
  }
}

private void StartCalls()
{
    int maxLines = 5;

    if (_ivrCallsQueue.Count < maxLines)
    {
        maxLines = _ivrCallsQueue.Count;
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++)
   {
       DataTable workingCall = new DataTable();

       _ivrCallsQueue.TryDequeue(out workingCall);

       BackgroundWorker ivrCaller = new BackgroundWorker();

       _ivrCallers.Add(ivrCaller);

            ivrCaller.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
          {
                RequestIVR(workingCall, Convert.ToInt32(workingCall.Rows[2][0].ToString()));
                _ivrCallers.Remove(ivrCaller);
            };

            ivrCaller.RunWorkerCompleted += (bw_AnalyzeResults);

            ivrCaller.RunWorkerAsync();
   }
}

private void bw_AnalyzeResults(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable workingCall = new DataTable();

    if (_ivrCallsQueue.Count != 0)
    {
        _ivrCallsQueue.TryDequeue(out workingCall);

        BackgroundWorker ivrCaller = new BackgroundWorker();

        ivrCaller.DoWork += delegate(object completeSender, DoWorkEventArgs completeArgs)
        {
            RequestIVR(workingCall, Convert.ToInt32(workingCall.Rows[2][0].ToString()));
            _ivrCallers.Remove(ivrCaller);
        };

        ivrCaller.RunWorkerCompleted += (bw_AnalyzeResults);

        ivrCaller.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

private void RequestIVR(DataTable workingTable,int fnActionItemID)
{
     var urlRequest = "http://uccx_http_trigger:9080/test?strTestMode=1&strTaskID=" + fnActionItemID;

    var webClient = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true, Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy };
    DecodeResponseType(GetValueFromElement("Response Code was&nbsp;", webClient.DownloadString(urlRequest)));
  }
```

Comment: Your code generally is quite scatter gun and I can see lots of oddities... In `Process` method you have a for loop `row` which is a `DataRow` but storing a `DataTable`? You are dequeuing twice. Jumping all over the place... Not surprised you've stumped yourself. I think you may want to come to it afresh and think what your logic should really be doing.

Comment: What should happen if `TryDequeue` returns `false`?

Comment: @Dialecticus i feel like no where in this code does TryDequeue return false.

Comment: @Belogix While I agree, this is the simplest solution. The process method returns a dataset of integers. Each integer is plugging into GetActionItemFromID, which returns a datatable. Each datatable has the info to make the call, so each datatable is added to the queue. I don't see how this is abnormally strange?

Comment: How is your `Process()` method started?

Comment: This is called by a service's OnStart() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will spawn at most five threads that each attempt to pull the next item from the queue and process it.  If the queue is empty the attempt will fail and the thread will simply exit:

```
    private List<System.Threading.Thread> Threads = new List<System.Threading.Thread>();
    private ConcurrentQueue<DataTable> _ivrCallsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DataTable>();

    private void StartCalls()
    {
        int maxLines = Math.Min(5 , _ivrCallsQueue.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++ )
        {
            System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
            {
                DataTable workingCall;
                while (_ivrCallsQueue.TryDequeue(out workingCall))
                {
                    RequestIVR(workingCall, Convert.ToInt32(workingCall.Rows[2][0].ToString()));
                }
            });
            Threads.Add(T);
            T.Start();
        }
    }
```

The threads will keep running until all the items have been processed.

Comment: im going to try this looks promising. So thread t will just dispose of itself upon finishing the while loop?

Comment: Right.  They simply "die" when the while loop drops out.  If the whole process is to be started over then you should clear out the List holding the old (dead) threads.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bw_AnalyzeResults` does pretty much the same thing that `StartCalls()` does. In other words, when the background worker has finished its work, you immediately enqueue the same work to happen again, recursively forever?

By the looks of it, you want `bw_AnalyzeResults` to analyze the results returned by calling your web service. That is not what is happening at the moment.

The code below taken from the `bw_AnalyzeResults` event handler is scheduling a background job and making itself handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. So, presumably the software keeps going around and around executing `bw_AnalyzeResults` forever until you kill the process?

```
private void bw_AnalyzeResults(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ivrCaller.DoWork += delegate(object completeSender, DoWorkEventArgs completeArgs)
    {
        RequestIVR(workingCall, Convert.ToInt32(workingCall.Rows[2][0].ToString()));
        _ivrCallers.Remove(ivrCaller);
    };
    ivrCaller.RunWorkerCompleted += (bw_AnalyzeResults);
}
```

Comment: Analyze results will do that in the future. I'm assuming with analyze results, that by calling TryDequeue that it does not do the same work, it does the next item in the queue?

Comment: For your edit, the main thread has a while loop for the count of the number of backgorund workers currently working, once the queue is reduced to 0, the bw removes itself from the list. Once the list hits 0, the main thread moves on.

Comment: the ... is rather important, once it finishes with its work, it removes itself from the list so it is no longer working.

Comment: You are already iterating over the jobs in `Process`? why do you need to enqeue jobs in `bw_AnalyzeResults`? Wouldn't the software be a lot simpler if you had one method start the jobs and another one process the results?

Comment: I am limited to 5 background workers with hundreds of items in the queue. is there another way? Its like when a backgorund worker reports completed, the background worker gets erased, a new one is created if there is still work to be done to replace the one who just finished